# ede-cpp-root-project is missing

Tags: cedet

The cedet info I am using with emacs 23.4.1

```
ECB 2.40 uses CEDET 1.0 (contains semantic 2.0, eieio 1.3, speedbar <unknown version>).
```

I am trying to create a cpp-root-project for out-of-source-tree building, however, when I try to create a project definition using

```
(ede-cpp-root-project "project-root"
                      :file "~/dev/gorgon/build/dummy-makefile"
                      :include-path '("/Source")
                      ;:system-include-path '("~/linux")
)
```

by requiring the file containing above code to load with

```
(require 'projects)
```

it gives following error

```
Symbol's function definition is void : ede-cpp-root-project
```

at first I thought maybe this "feature" is lacking so I tried to list available projects from ede projects and it listed

```
Automake
make
```

My question is does this functionality supported in CEDET 1.0 or am I doing something wrong?

the codes related to ede in my init.el file

```
(global-ede-mode 1)
(semantic-mode 1)
(ede-enable-generic-projects)
(global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode)
(global-semantic-idle-completions-mode)
(global-semantic-decoration-mode)
(global-semantic-highlight-func-mode)
(global-semantic-show-unmatched-syntax-mode)
```

Comment: Welcome.  Does the error message really have the final `s`?

Comment: It was a mistake. 's' does not belong to error message.

Comment: `(require 'ede/cpp-root)` or something ?

Comment: tried both `(require 'ede/cpp-root)` and `(require 'ede/cpp-root-project)` just to be sure. I get `error: file for ede-cpp-root must be a file` for the former; `can not open load file` for the latter. Not sure if relevant but I did not install CEDET from its repo. I think I am using built-in version.

Comment: The `:file` argument must be a existing directory.

Comment: according to [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ede/ede_002dcpp_002droot.html), it should be a file located at the root of the project: [...] _and the filename to an actual file at the root of your project. It might be a Makefile, a README file. Whatever. It doesn’t matter. It’s just a key to hang the rest of EDE off of._ I don't think that's the issue. I put the root directory instead of a file located in root directory there, it is the same results. It complains about failing to find that function definition rather than the variables inside the project definition.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `Commentary: for`../ede/ede-cpp-root.el`, the file should only be the FILENAME and not a path. Try changing to

```
(ede-cpp-root-project "project-root"
                  :file "dummy-makefile"
                  :include-path '("/Source" "~/dev/gorgon/build")
                  ;:system-include-path '("~/linux")
 )
```

cedet-1.1 is very old. Try updating to cedet-2.0.